# Access to page contents from PhaseListiner

Tags: jsf

I need move all JS scripts from "head" tag to bottom of "body" tag to increase a speed of application. I know, that need use PhaseListener, but how to get page content from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your actual question is: How do I render JavaScript references at the page bottom rather than at the HEAD area?

I recommend to use the h:outputScript tag which ensures that a script gets references only once and with that you can control the rendering position.

Doc: 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/outputScript.html

Example:

```
<h:outputScript library="js" name="myScript.js" target="body" />
```

This will render the script reference at the bottom of page body, independent from where you placed the Facelet tag on your view.